# Compare numbers from two different lists

Tags: xml, list, variables, compare, xslt-1.0

i'm super new to XSL programming and i have the following xml;

```
<InRoads productName="OpenRoads Designer CONNECT Edition - 2020 Release 3" productVersion="10.09.00.91" linearUnits="Metric" angularUnits="Degrees" isInternationalFoot="false" commandName="Geometry Report" > 
  <GeometryProject name="Default" file="C:\Users\Dennis.Chung\Desktop\GAP RD\280421 new kerb setout\RIA-AEC-MOD-130-310-00-3D-CTRL-ROAD_KERBS.dgn" lastRevisedDate="4/30/2021 21:31:11" > 
     <HorizontalAlignment name="Unnamed" lastRevisedDate="4/30/2021 06:58:57" area="0.000000000" perimeter="90.347392542" closingDistance="90.347392542" closingDirection="-3.059276459318" closingPrecision="1.000000000" northingClosingError="7.428657504" eastingClosingError="90.041470373" fromFeature="false" > 
            <HorizontalElements > 
                <HorizontalLine length="90.347392542" direction="0.082316194272" elementNumber="1" > 
                    <Start northing="5838252.765890940" easting="299195.240389283" elevation="-0.160761453" pointType="POB" type="START" name="" > 
                <station internalStation="0.000000000" externalStation="0.000000000" externalStationName="" /> 
                    </Start> 
                    <End northing="5838260.194548440" easting="299285.281859655" elevation="-0.502611998" pointType="POE" type="END" name="" > 
                <station internalStation="90.347392542" externalStation="90.347393000" externalStationName="" /> 
            </End> 
    </HorizontalLine> 
</HorizontalElements> 
<HorizontalCurveSets > 
    <CurvesetPoint curveSetID="0" tangentDirectionStart="0.082316194272" pointType="POB" type="START" curveSetStartElement="1" > 
        <GeometryPoint northing="5838252.765890940" easting="299195.240389283" elevation="-0.160761453" pointType="POB" type="START" name="" > 
            <station internalStation="0.000000000" externalStation="0.000000000" externalStationName="" /> 
        </GeometryPoint> 
    </CurvesetPoint> 
    <CurvesetPoint curveSetID="1" tangentDirectionEnd="0.082316194272" pointType="POE" type="END" curveSetStopElement="1" > 
        <GeometryPoint northing="5838260.194548440" easting="299285.281859655" elevation="-0.502611998" pointType="POE" type="END" name="" > 
            <station internalStation="90.347392542" externalStation="90.347393000" externalStationName="" /> 
        </GeometryPoint> 
    </CurvesetPoint> 
</HorizontalCurveSets> 
<HorizontalEventPoints > 
    <HorizontalComputedEventPoints > 
        <HorizontalEventPoint eventType="stationEvent" radius="0.000000000" grade="0.04251083947571" tangentialDirection="0.082316194272" radialDirection="4.794705174656" > 
            <GeometryPoint northing="5838252.765890940" easting="299195.240389283" elevation="-0.160761453" pointType="POB" type="START" name="" > 
                <station internalStation="0.000000000" externalStation="0.000000000" externalStationName="" /> 
            </GeometryPoint> 
        </HorizontalEventPoint> 
        <HorizontalEventPoint eventType="stationEvent" radius="0.000000000" grade="0.02781531466054" tangentialDirection="0.082316194272" radialDirection="4.794705174656" > 
            <GeometryPoint northing="5838254.410356220" easting="299215.172667977" elevation="0.638006868" pointType="POT" type="POT" name="" > 
                <station internalStation="20.000000000" externalStation="20.000000000" externalStationName="" /> 
            </GeometryPoint> 
        </HorizontalEventPoint> 
        <HorizontalEventPoint eventType="stationEvent" radius="0.000000000" grade="-0.01416036580177" tangentialDirection="0.082316194272" radialDirection="4.794705174656" > 
            <GeometryPoint northing="5838256.054821500" easting="299235.104946671" elevation="0.774556356" pointType="POT" type="POT" name="" > 
                <station internalStation="40.000000000" externalStation="40.000000000" externalStationName="" /> 
            </GeometryPoint> 
        </HorizontalEventPoint> 
        <HorizontalEventPoint eventType="stationEvent" radius="0.000000000" grade="-0.02603425086589" tangentialDirection="0.082316194272" radialDirection="4.794705174656" > 
            <GeometryPoint northing="5838257.699286780" easting="299255.037225365" elevation="0.287459632" pointType="POT" type="POT" name="" > 
                <station internalStation="60.000000000" externalStation="60.000000000" externalStationName="" /> 
            </GeometryPoint> </HorizontalEventPoint> 
        <HorizontalEventPoint eventType="stationEvent" radius="0.000000000" grade="-0.02603425086589" tangentialDirection="0.082316194272" radialDirection="4.794705174656" > 
            <GeometryPoint northing="5838259.343752050" easting="299274.969504060" elevation="-0.233225385" pointType="POT" type="POT" name="" > 
                <station internalStation="80.000000000" externalStation="80.000000000" externalStationName="" /> 
            </GeometryPoint> 
        </HorizontalEventPoint> 
        <HorizontalEventPoint eventType="stationEvent" radius="0.000000000" grade="-0.02603425086589" tangentialDirection="0.082316194272" radialDirection="4.794705174656" > 
            <GeometryPoint northing="5838260.194548440" easting="299285.281859655" elevation="-0.502611998" pointType="POE" type="END" name="" > 
                <station internalStation="90.347392542" externalStation="90.347393000" externalStationName="" /> 
            </GeometryPoint> 
        </HorizontalEventPoint> 
    </HorizontalComputedEventPoints> 
<HorizontalNormalEventPoints > 
    <EventPointLists > 
        <EventPointList name="rr" > 
            <HorizontalEventPoint eventType="stationEvent" radius="0.000000000" grade="-0.00820233459715" tangentialDirection="0.082316194272" radialDirection="4.794705174656" > 
                <GeometryPoint northing="5838255.821405970" easting="299232.275757552" elevation="0.806297990" pointType="POT" type="POT" name="" > 
                    <station internalStation="37.161198514" externalStation="37.161199000" externalStationName="" /> 
                </GeometryPoint> 
            </HorizontalEventPoint> 
            <HorizontalEventPoint eventType="stationEvent" radius="0.000000000" grade="-0.02603425086589" tangentialDirection="0.082316194272" radialDirection="4.794705174656" > 
                <GeometryPoint northing="5838258.192304850" easting="299261.013012043" elevation="0.131355925" pointType="POT" type="POT" name="" > 
                    <station internalStation="65.996089830" externalStation="65.996090000" externalStationName="" /> 
                </GeometryPoint> </HorizontalEventPoint> 
            <HorizontalEventPoint eventType="stationEvent" radius="0.000000000" grade="-0.02603425086589" tangentialDirection="0.082316194272" radialDirection="4.794705174656" > 
                <GeometryPoint northing="5838258.377685960" easting="299263.259984364" elevation="0.072658932" pointType="POT" type="POT" name="" > 
                    <station internalStation="68.250696395" externalStation="68.250696000" externalStationName="" /> 
                </GeometryPoint> 
            </HorizontalEventPoint> 
        </EventPointList> 
    </EventPointLists> 
</HorizontalNormalEventPoints> 
</HorizontalEventPoints> 
</HorizontalAlignment> 
</GeometryProject> 
</InRoads>
```

i need to be able to output the stations from both list (HorizontalEventPoint and HorizontalNoramlEventPoint) in correct order, so the output chainage should be;

```
0    
20
37.161199000
40
60
65.996090000
68.250696395
80
90.347392542
```

i can list the stations from the HorizontalEventPoints and produce something like this;

```
0    
20
40
60
80
90.347392542
```

but have no idea how to do it for both lists.

all i have is something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas- 
microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:cif="cif">
<xsl:param name="xslShowHelp" select="cif:xslShowHelp"/>
<xsl:param name="xslRootDirectory" select="cif:xslRootDirectory"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="gridOut" 
select="cif:SetGridOut(number(InRoads/@outputGridScaleFactor))"/>
<html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" 
{$xslRootDirectory}/_Themes/engineer/theme.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$xslShowHelp = 'true'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="StyleSheetHelp"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:for-each select="InRoads">
                        <center>
<h2 lang="en">CL -&#xa0; <xsl:value-of select="GeometryProject/HorizontalAlignment/@name"/></h2>
                            
</center>
<xsl:for-each select="GeometryProject">
                            
            
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead style="display:table-header-group">
                                    <tr>
                                        
<th lang="en" valign="bottom">Type</th>
<th lang="en" valign="bottom">Chainage</th>
<th lang="en" valign="bottom">Easting</th>
<th lang="en" valign="bottom">Northing</th>
<th lang="en" valign="bottom">Level</th>
<th lang="en" valign="bottom">Bearing</th>
<th lang="en" valign="bottom">Rad/Spiral</th>
<th lang="en" valign="bottom">A.Length</th>
<th lang="en" valign="bottom">D.Angle</th>
</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
 <xsl:for-each select="HorizontalAlignment">
 <xsl:for-each select="HorizontalElements">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="//HorizontalLine | //HorizontalCircle | //HorizontalSpiral"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
                                        
 </xsl:for-each>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>




<xsl:template match="HorizontalLine">
<xsl:variable name="startStation" select="Start/station/@internalStation"/>
<xsl:variable name="endStation" select="End/station/@internalStation"/>
<xsl:if test="Start">

<tr>

<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="Start/@pointType = 'POB'">
   <td align="center" lang="en">IP</td>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="Start/@pointType = 'PI'">
   <td align="center" lang="en">IP</td>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="cif:pointType(string(Start/@pointType))"/></td>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

<td align="center" style="white-space:nowrap">
            <xsl:value-of select="cif:stationFormat(number(Start/station/@externalStation), string(Start/station/@externalStationName))"/>
</td>
<td align="center">
<xsl:value-of select="cif:ordinateFormat(number(Start/@easting))"/>
</td>
<td align="center">
<xsl:value-of select="cif:ordinateFormat(number(Start/@northing))"/>
        </td>
<td align="center">
<xsl:value-of select="cif:ordinateFormat(number(Start/@elevation))"/>
        </td>
<td align="center">
<xsl:value-of select="cif:directionFormat(number(@direction))"/>
</td>
<td>&#xa0;</td>
<td>&#xa0;</td>
<td>&#xa0;</td>
   </tr>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:for-each select="../../HorizontalEventPoints">
<xsl:variable name="list1" select="*/HorizontalEventPoint[GeometryPoint/station/@internalStation &gt; $startStation]"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$list1[GeometryPoint/station/@internalStation &lt; $endStation]">
<tr>
<td>&#xa0;</td>
<td align="center" style="white-space:nowrap">
<xsl:value-of select="cif:stationFormat(number(GeometryPoint/station/@externalStation), string(GeometryPoint/station/@externalStationName))"/>
        </td>
    <td align="center">
            <xsl:value-of select="cif:ordinateFormat(number(GeometryPoint/@easting))"/>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <xsl:value-of select="cif:ordinateFormat(number(GeometryPoint/@northing))"/>
        </td>
<td align="center">
            <xsl:value-of select="cif:ordinateFormat(number(GeometryPoint/@elevation))"/>
        </td>
        <td>&#xa0;</td>
        <td>&#xa0;</td>
        <td>&#xa0;</td>
        <td>&#xa0;</td>
         </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:if test="End[@pointType = 'POE']">
  <tr>
     
<td align="center" lang="en">IP</td>
<td align="right" style="white-space:nowrap">
<xsl:value-of select="cif:stationFormat(number(End/station/@externalStation), string(End/station/@externalStationName))"/>
        </td>
    <td align="center">
            <xsl:value-of select="cif:ordinateFormat(number(End/@easting))"/>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <xsl:value-of select="cif:ordinateFormat(number(End/@northing))"/>
        </td>
<td align="center">
            <xsl:value-of select="cif:ordinateFormat(number(End/@elevation))"/>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <xsl:value-of select="cif:directionFormat(number(@direction))"/>
        </td>
        <td>&#xa0;</td>
        <td>&#xa0;</td>
        <td>&#xa0;</td>
  </tr>
 
</xsl:if>


</xsl:template>
**strong text**</xsl:stylesheet>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question and add the input and the expected output **as code**, not as picture. Also explain exactly what is the "correct order" - IOW, what is the logic that should be applied here.

Comment: HI Michael, i have re-posted the code and question.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you show can be produced quite easily by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/InRoads">
    <xsl:for-each select="GeometryProject/HorizontalAlignment/HorizontalEventPoints/HorizontalComputedEventPoints/HorizontalEventPoint | GeometryProject/HorizontalAlignment/HorizontalEventPoints/HorizontalNormalEventPoints/EventPointLists/EventPointList/HorizontalEventPoint">
        <xsl:sort select="GeometryPoint/station/@internalStation" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="number(GeometryPoint/station/@internalStation)"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you can be sure that no `HorizontalEventPoint` element exists outside of the two lists you are interested in, you could shorten the code to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/InRoads">
    <xsl:for-each select="//HorizontalEventPoint">
        <xsl:sort select="GeometryPoint/station/@internalStation" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="number(GeometryPoint/station/@internalStation)"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

although this puts more burden on the processor to find all the  `HorizontalEventPoint` elements in the entire XML document.

Comment: hi,
thanks for the reply.
i will give this ago.
regards

Comment: hi Michael,
the code works perfect! thanks!!
just out of interest, is there a way to detect duplicate values from the two lists?
for example, if there's a chainage 20 in both lists i just want to show only one of them and not both.
thanks

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html. If not, post a new question.